# insert query is giving ORA-01722: invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I created a stock table with the below query

```
CREATE TABLE stock
  (
    product_id REFERENCES product ,
    product_name REFERENCES product ,
    color    VARCHAR2(20) ,
    memory   VARCHAR2(20) ,
    in_stock NUMBER(3)
  );
```

I tried to insert a row into this using the below query:

```
insert into stock values(8881,'Nexus 4','Black','2GB-16GB',3);
```

and it is giving **ORA-01722: invalid number error** , I know why the error comes , but I can't figure out what wrong I have done

product table :

```
product_id ..number , product_name .. varchar2
```

adding a pic

[image]

Comment: just do one thing to find the error : insert into stock values except in_stock ..and let me know if error :)

Comment: `insert into stock(product_id , product_name, color , memory) values(8881,'Nexus 4','Black','2GB-16GB')` .. it is giving same error invalid number

Comment: last thing try inserting all except product_id

Comment: The `create table` statement you posted isn't valid syntax.  The first two columns are missing data types and the foreign key constraints aren't valid syntax.  What is the actual definition of the `stock` table?

Comment: @utility did that ..same error and even tried to add only product_name , color and memory ..still same error

Comment: @JustinCave  ... i did this before also ...never gave me such type of error and i have been using this syntax for quite a while without error

Comment: while selecting data too error ?

Comment: i don't have any data in the `stock` table

Comment: What is the definition of `product`?  Is `product_id` the primary key of `product`?  If so, you're implicitly defining `product_name` as a child of `product.product_id` which is, presumably, a number.  "Nexus 4" is not a valid number.

Comment: i edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`product_id` is the primary key of `product` and is a `number` column.  When you define a table

```
CREATE TABLE stock
  (
    product_id REFERENCES product ,
    product_name REFERENCES product ,
    color    VARCHAR2(20) ,
    memory   VARCHAR2(20) ,
    in_stock NUMBER(3)
  );
```

both `product_id` and `product_name` are being implicitly defined as `number` columns that reference the `product_id` column from `product`.  Since `product_name` is defined as a `number`, you can't insert the string "Nexus 4".

It makes no sense to have a `product_name` column in the `stock` table.  It already exists in the `product` table which is where it belongs.  It violates basic rules of normalization to store the same information in multiple locations.  I would strongly suspect that `color` and `memory` ought to exist in the `product` table as well rather than in the `stock` table.

Your DDL appears to be valid syntax (rather shockingly) but it is very, very unusual.  I've been dealing with Oracle for many years and I've never seen anyone create a table this way.  It appears to be valid but it's going to throw off anyone that has to support your application after you.  It would be much more reasonable to be explicit

```
CREATE TABLE stock
  (
    product_id NUMBER REFERENCES product( product_id ) ,
    product_name VARCHAR2(40) , -- This shouldn't be in this table
    color    VARCHAR2(20) , -- Nor should this
    memory   VARCHAR2(20) , -- Nor should this
    in_stock NUMBER(3)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The definition for `references` says your syntax is invalid: http://psoug.org/definition/REFERENCES.htm.

How does it know which column in products it's meant to match? You need to tell it.

Go to one of the tables you have created using this method and script it out and you will see you need to specify the column. You won't find any creation scripts without a column in the references

Your DDL doesn't match the screenshot. The screenshot has `Category_ID` and your DDL does not.

If you were runing that sample `INSERT` statement without a target column list against the table *screenshot*, that would explain your error.

Never *ever* code an insert without a target column list. It invites bugs. (not to mention it's makes it look like you're lazy)

Comment: I assumed that the syntax was invalid because I'd never seen it before and it doesn't seem to confirm to any syntax I've seen documented.  But actually running it, it appears to be valid.  I'm more than a little surprised...

Comment: Huh! So what column does it pick? Does it go by name or somethig? I should retract my huffy statement but the comment about not using an insert column list still stands!

Comment: It appears that it just uses the primary key of the parent table both to define the data type in the child and to define the foreign key.  But I wouldn't want to swear that it always works that way!  Particularly given that an hour ago, I would have bet good money that the syntax was fundamentally invalid.

Comment: I guess that makes sense since you can't define a foreign key to a non primary key (in SQL Server anyway - not sure about Oracle). It's intriguing that it **overrides** the explicitly defined data type in the child! That's really breaking rules!

Comment: You can define a foreign key in Oracle that references a unique key in the parent other than the primary key.  It isn't overriding the explicit data type in the child, it's inferring the data type.  In this case we expect that `product_name` is a string.  But it's not specified in the DDL and since the primary key of `product` is a `number`, `product_name` in the child becomes a numeric column.  Which is all rather non-obvious from looking at the code.

Comment: This is one of those questions that I should have read in more detail. I also assumed the OP would have defined the data type in the DDL.